# C# - when using a type, will its constructor be called?

Tags: c#

For example, when compile `public string _name`, will type string's constructor be called?

Comment: No, it won't call the constructor until you create an instance of the class. In your snippet what you are doing is similar to just creating a pointer which points to a specific type (string) but still no object is created.

Comment: @mok actually if you were to use this in say Main, then it is an object set as Null. Of a primitive type

Comment: @mok I feel his question requires more substance. There is no code of the class. But regardless I supplied an answer that shows a class example with multiple constructors and how to call those constructors upon creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but if you need to call a string constructor, you could use this:

```
_name = new string(...);
```

You must replace the "..." with valid parameters. If you don't know, which parameter are necessary, look at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This is more an example of an instantiation of a class, not a class constructor.

Comment: @Edward The question is about whether the constructor is called or not, which is addressed more or less in this answer.

Comment: @mok truthfully this whole question is vague as the only code he shows is a field of a class at most. And nothing to show it actually even belongs to a  class.

Answer (score 0):

No, in your case the field `_name` will be set as `null` (like any other reference type).

You can simply do `public string _name = String.Empty`

Comment: thanks,but when will a constructor be called, is it only when new a item

Comment: in this case,when will `string`'s constructor be called

Comment: Your question confuses me a bit. If you are asking "When the field _name is going to be assigned?" the answer is, before the class which _name belongs is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the field _name, then its constructor will be called. For example:

```
class A
{
}

class B
{
}

class C
{
    private A _a;
    private B _b = new B(); // B's constructor will be called here. It will be executed before C's constructor

    public C()
    {
        _a = new A(); // A's constructor will be called here
    }
}
```

In your example, if you are not initialize the _name, compiler will set it's value to null, that means no constructor will be called. But if you set it to an value, its constructor will be called.

Answer (score 0):

what you have is a field of a class at most and as DesertFox's answer shows you can provide a default value, but after c# version (6?) I suggest using properties with defaults value. Properties are in the form of

```
 public int name { get { return _name;} set{ _name = value; } }
```

Your title is very confusing. If you want a constructor in a custom class you have to write it like this

```
class Node {
    private int _node; //field
    public int node {get;set;}  = 0  //property
    public Node() { } //constructor taking 0 parameters
    public Node(int node){ this.node = node;} //constructor taking 1 parameter
   //you don't even need "this" as it knows which you are referring to
}
```

now to call your constructor you could use many ways like

```
Node myNode = new Node(){};
Node myNode = new Node(1){};
Node myNode = new Node(){node=1;};
```